# How to store rspec test messages

Tags: ruby, rspec

Following is my sample code for testing:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Book do
  before :each do
    @book = Book.new 'Title', 'Author', :category
  end

  describe "#title" do
    it 'returns the correct title' do
      @book.title.should == 'Title'
    end
  end

  describe "#author" do
    it 'returns the correct author' do
      @book.author.should == 'Author'
    end
  end
end
```

Here, we've two tests:

1. Book #title returns the correct title
2. Book #author returns the correct author

These above messages are displayed only when tests fail.

I've to save those two test messages and their respective results in log file. In order to achieve that I'll first have to store those test messages in objects. How can I store those test messages in object? So that I can use them while writing to log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the documentation format when you run RSpec: `rspec --format doc` which will output all of the results. If you want, you can redirect that to a file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being able to use the `--format doc` approach described in the other answer, you can access the concatenation of the descriptions within each `it` block via the following:

```
example.metadata[:full_description]
```